# iOS app Crashes randomly after integrating revmob

Tags: ios

I am working on a application which is working fine previously.  I just integrated the revmob into the application.  Below is the code that i implemented in the the app delegate

```
- (void)showBannerWindow 
{
    self.bannerWindow = [[RevMobAds session] banner];  
    [self.bannerWindow loadWithSuccessHandler:^(RevMobBanner *banner) {
    [banner showAd];
    [self revmobAdDidReceive];
    } andLoadFailHandler:^(RevMobBanner *banner, NSError *error) {
    [self revmobAdDidFailWithError:error];
    } onClickHandler:^(RevMobBanner *banner) {
    [self revmobUserClickedInTheAd];}];
}

-(void)removeBannerWindow
{
     [self.bannerWindow hideAd];
}
```

I am using this app delegate method in the various controller. I am just hiding and Showing the revmobwindow banner ads on push and pop.

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate showBannerWindow];
```

Now the application crashes randomly every time i getting errors with "setStatus" like the following.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
 reason: '-[CALayer setStatus:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xac51e40'

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
 reason: '-[NSURL setStatus:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xafa3530'
```

Comment: Looks like this is a bug on the RevMob SDK (http://stackoverflow.com/q/21333170/634185).

Comment: @diogot yes it seems a bugs in RevMob SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug on the RevMob SDK ([stackoverflow.com/q/21333170/634185](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21333170/634185))