# RevMob Banner Ads "CAStatus layer" error crashing App

Tags: ios, objective-c, revmob

I am trying to integrate RevMob , i successfully integrated and full Screen Ads are also running without error.

But when i try to show banner Ads , they also comes but if ones i hide them on any view controller and  try to show them on other view controller , Application used to crash .

What i did uptill now please have a look --

> First in AppDelegate i did this --

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

     [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"APP_ID"];  
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
     [[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];

       [[RevMobAds session]showBanner];
}
```

> Now for Example if from my **RootViewController  -- A** moves to
>   another **ViewController -- B** ,in ViewController - B i am hiding
>   this RevMob like this --

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  [[RevMobAds session] hideBanner];

}
```

> and when i press back button on **ViewController -- B** i show
>   revmob back on **RootViewController  -- A**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
   [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];

}
```

but i does get crash between this transition and i get this crash error -

```
[CALayer setStatus:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe7d4010
2014-01-24 18:17:37.088 StudentsApp[4590:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer setStatus:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe7d4010'
```

Comment: You should't use your AppId on a post.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug on the RevMob SDK http://stackoverflow.com/q/21178788/634185